# comparing other table for missing data with not exists

Tags: oracle

I have two tabls

table 1

```
name     | column

animals  | fish
animals  | cow
buildings| house
cars     | BMW
cars     | Ford
```

table 2

```
name     | column
         |
animals  | fish
         |
buildings| house

cars     | Ford
```

I trying to write a query shows the missing 2 columns ( bmw and cow) like this:

```
name     | column
animals  | Cow
Cars     | BMW
```

I tried to write such query:

> select t1.column 
>   from table 1 t1 
>   where not exists ( select 1 from table2 t2  where t1.column = t2.column)

but it giving me empty result , can anyone fix the query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select name,column from table1
minus
select name,column from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 t1 WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t1.column = t2.column);
```

**SQLFiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/399b2d/7